# how can I improve this if else statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this function for finding the direction of ray in Cartesian plane:

```
def direction(self):
    if 180 > self.angle > 90:
        return (-1, +1)
    elif 90 > self.angle > 0:
        return (+1, +1)
    elif 0 > self.angle > -90:
        return (+1, -1)
    elif -90 > self.angle > -180:
        return (-1, -1)
```

This looks kinda bulky. Is there a simpler way to phrase it? It simply gives me the quadrant a ray is going based on the angle.

Comment: For your reference, your code returns None for any angle that is an integer multiple of 90. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a conditional statement at all if you use [`math.copysign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign) and the fundamental trig functions:

```
from math import copysign, sin, cos, pi

def direction(angle):
    angle *= pi / 180
    return copysign(1, cos(angle)), copysign(1, sin(angle))
```

If you insist on using conditionals, you can separate out the comparisons for two instead of four cases:

```
def direction(angle):
    angle %= 360
    x = -1 if 90 < angle < 270 else +1
    y = -1 if 180 < angle else +1
    return x, y
```

In fact, you can use the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int` to remove the conditionals entirely in a different manner:

```
def direction(angle):
    angle %= 360
    x = 1 - 2 * (90 < angle < 270)
    y = 1 - 2 * (180 < angle)
    return x, y
```

Using cyclic functions like `sin`, `cos` and modulo (`%`) will make your code handle wraparound better.

These formulations will also do a better job of handling corner cases. Your original function would return `None` for an angle of `90`. These two versions would not. You can adjust the conditions (e.g. replace `<` with `<=` sometimes) to make the corner cases work out precisely the way you want.

Comment: yeh it is concise but I just realised that if else statement is much faster than other methods I tried including this one

Comment: @pytherhub. Updated with a simpler conditional

Comment: @pytherhub. One more update. No need to use conditionals. The whole thing reduces to a pair of boolean expressions with an add-multiply.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me, You can replace the last elif with an else instead like this

```
def direction(self):
        if 180>self.angle>90:
            return (-1,+1)
        elif 90>self.angle>0:
            return (1,1)
        elif 0>self.angle>-90:
            return (1,-1)
        else:
            return (-1,-1)
```

Comment: no I wanted more simpler method because there is a pattern

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the angle into the quadrant number (0, 1, etc.) and use such as an index in an array:

```
return [(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1)]\\
       [int(self.angle % 360) // 90]
```

This works even when `self.angle` is not an integer.